# Python Deque Array adding to array crashes python

Tags: python, arrays, deque

I am working on a double ended queue in python and everything seems to be working fine except for my preappend(adding to the front) method. When I call upon this method in main it crashes python and I am super confused as to why, here is my code:

```
import ctypes

class dequeArray:

def __init__(self):
    """Create an empty Array """
    self._capacity = 4
    self._data = self.makeArray(self._capacity)
    self._dataSize = 0
    self._front = 0

def makeArray(self, capacity):
    capacity = self._capacity
    return (self._capacity * ctypes.py_object)()

def isEmpty(self):
    return self._dataSize == 0

def __len__(self):
    return self._dataSize

def _userIndex2BlockIndex(self, userIndex):
    return (self._front + userIndex)% self._capacity

def __getitem__(self, userIndex):
    return self._data[userIndex]

def __setitem__(self, userIndex, value):
    self._data[self._front(userIndex)] = value

def preappend(self, item):
    if self._dataSize == 0:
        self._data[self._front] = item
        self._dataSize += 1

    elif self._dataSize != self._capacity:
        for e in range(self._dataSize-1,0,-1):
            self._data[e] = self._data[e-1]
        self._data[self._front] = item
        self._dataSize += 1
    else:
         for e in range(self._capacity-1,0,-1):
            self._data[e] = self._data[e-1]
         self._data[self._front] = item
```

in main I create an empty deque
    d = dequeArray()

then test len(d) and that works fine but when I do
    d.preappend(2)
it crashes python... Please help

Comment: Can you also post the output you are getting from Python?

Comment: Not to be a jerk, but why on Earth are you writing this? `ctypes` makes it really easy to segfault Python, and should only be used if you legitimately need its features. Nothing you are doing here requires `ctypes`; even if you can't use `collections.deque` for whatever reason, simulating it with Python level types, e.g. a `list` of `list`s, would be far safer than mucking about with `ctypes` containers for Python level types (I shudder to think what a small error would do to the reference counts).

Comment: It crashes Python? Or your program? Please post any error messages you receive.

Comment: @kindall there isn't any good output to post, it executes to show the length is 0 and then directly after when it tries to process d.preappend(8) or any number it crashes and says python has unexpectedly quit. I am using IDLE on a Mac

Comment: @ShadowRanger using ctypes to formulate my array is required for this assignment.

Comment: @kindall I have an append method to that works and i am able to append elements but as soon as i try to pretend it crashes

Answer (score 0):

In the general, deques() never crash when used with normal Python objects.

With *ctypes*, all bets are off because C calls by pass all the invariant checks, type safety checks, pointer/index range checks etc.

Deques only access limited features for an object created with *ctypes*.  At a minimum, it needs to support reference counting.  To display, it needs a **repr**.  To remove() or index(), it needs to support **eq**().